# formula to find no. of different cyclic structures in $A_n$ and no. of elements in $A_n$ having a particular cyclic structure

Tags: abstract-algebra

Are there  formulas to find no. of different cyclic structures in $A_n$ and no. of elements in $A_n$ having a particular cyclic  structure?

> In $S_n$ we have such formulas.
>
> No. of different cyclic structures in $S_n =P(n)$ where $P(n)$ is the no. of partitions of $n$.
>
> Also no. of elements in $S_n$ having the cyclic  structure ${l_1}^{n_1}{l_2}^{n_2}...{l_r}^{n_r}$ is ${n!\over {l_1}^{n_1}{l_2}^{n_2}...{l_r}^{n_r}.n_1!n_2!...n_r!}$ where ${l_i}^{n_i}$ are ${n_i}$ cycles of length  ${l_i}$ for $i=1,2,...,r$.
>
> I want to know that, are there such corresponding formulas for $A_n$ ?

Comment: The number of elements of given cycle structure formulae for $A_n$ are the same as for $S_n$ but apply only to even permutations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Community Wiki answer to avoid leaving it unanswered:*

From Mark Bennet's comment:

The number of elements of given cycle structure formulae for $A_n$ are the same as for $S_n$ but apply only to even permutations.